# Access Exchange's public folders in Mail app on Lion?

Tags: mail.app, exchange-activesync

Lion's Mail app smoothly setup my connection to our company's Exchange server. However I cannot see the pubic folders anywhere.
Any hints how I can integrate them into Mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krumelur

Mail.app used to be able to see Public Folders on Exchange, but no longer has this ability.

Outlook 2011 and Entourage both support this feature.

Comment: Outlook 2011 for Mac has a bug that brings down our Exchange server. It keeps polling it several times per second. Entourage is discontinued, isn't it?

Comment: Yes Entourage is discontinued, it was replaced by a full version of Outlook in the lastest Mac Office release.  I know quite a few people still using Entourage on older versions of Office